# The operator <= is underdefined

Tags: java, methods

So I programmed a boolean method that returns true when a integer n, is in-between the range 0-10 and 90-100. But for some reason I get this under defined error which I am very confused about. Heres my code for my method:

```
public static boolean isEndy(int n){
    if(0 <= n <=10 || 90<=n<=100){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript? Please tag properly.

Comment: In any case there isn't such sequence of `<=`

Comment: Just change it to: `if ((0 <= n && n <= 10) || (90 <= n && n <= 100))`

Comment: This illustrates why it is a good idea to read a text book or do a tutorial, rather than relying on your intuition to figure out Java syntax.

Answer (score 7):

You can't compose two comparison operators like that, since the first `<=` operator would return a boolean and the second `<=` operator cannot be applied on a boolean and an int.

They must be joined with logical AND :

```
if((0 <= n && n <= 10) || (90 <= n && n <= 100))
```

Comment: you may skip the inner brackets